# SQL Server PHP Login Form

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I am currently trying to create a login form for a project I am working on, however I am struggling when it comes to comparing the Username and Password strings, to the entries I hold within my SQL Server database.

My SQL Database currently looks like this:

**Username** || **Password**

Store One || password

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action=''>
    <input type="text" name="user" color="white" placeholder="Username" required="required" class="input-txt" />
      <input type="password" name="pass" color="white" placeholder="Password" required="required" class="input-txt" />
      <div class="login-footer">             
        <button type="submit" name="submit"  class="btn btn--right"> Sign in  </button>
</form>
```

And here is my php I am currently trying to get working:

```
 <?php

    session_start();
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
        $server = "SQL2008.net.dcs.hull.ac.uk";
        $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"rde_506694");
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connectionInfo);
        if($conn === false)
        {
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. ");
        }
        else
        {
            $Username=$_POST['user'];
            $Password=$_POST['pass'];

            $describeQuery="SELECT username, password FROM LoginDetails
                            WHERE username = '$Username' AND password = '$Password'";
            $results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $describeQuery);

            if($results !== null)
            {                                               
                if($Username!=="" && $Password!=="")
                {
                    header("Location: http://webdev.net.dcs.hull.ac.uk/506694/WelcomePage.php", true, 301);
                    exit();
                }
                else
                {
                    $alert = "Your entered user name or password is incorrect";
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$alert');</script>";
                }
            }               
            else
            {
                echo ' No Records Found ';
            }
        }
        sqlsrv_close($conn);
    }

  ?>
```

Before anyone states; I am aware that my code is vunerable to SQL injection and I plan on implementing prevention for this at a later date.

My code at the moment accepts any entry, even though my php should only execute if my query returns results.

Any help on this please?

Comment: you need to check if a row exists and matches both criterias.

Comment: sqlsrv_query returns a resource, not a boolean.

Comment: *"Before anyone states; I am aware that my code is vunerable to SQL injection and I plan on implementing prevention for this at a later date."* - and the plain text passwords; what about those? You left that out. Honestly, why are you coding this only to have to recode later on?

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I think you've forgotten that the purpose of stack overflow is to help, not to judge. If you have a problem with the way I am going about my own tasks that's fine, but don't be offended when I say I don't care about you're views on it in the slightest.

Comment: I don't see where I "judged" you. Another purpose is to educate and we/I can't emphasize on that enough. I'm not offended here, and I value the opinion you gave. I actually thought I was doing you a favor. By using both a prepared statement and `password_hash()` right away or ASAP, was to get you started on the right foot.

Comment: To try and answer this; use `sqlsrv_num_rows()` https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-num-rows.php while using a fetching method. Those are listed in https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.sqlsrv.php